# How to i add a loop to stop multiple database entries?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When i hit my submit button it sends multiple entries to the database how can i set a loop here to stop this. I tried setting the datetime to only allow one entry at that time but the entries go in a second or two apart so that doesnt work.

I have updated this question with majority of code, i am unsure where abouts this error is coming from so any help would be appreciated.

```
   public AddSymptom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        symmanager = SymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        symptomfeedbackmanager = SymptomFeedbackManager.DefaultManager;

        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });

        GetUserSymptoms();

        //Set Label Titles
        lblTitle.Text = "Add Symptom";
        lblSubtutle.Text = "What symptom are you experiencing?";
        autoComplete.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeSentence | KeyboardFlags.Spellcheck);
        GetCorrectiveActions();

        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();

        GetSymptomHistory();


    }

    async Task GetUserSymptoms()
    {
        UserSymptoms = await usersymptommanager.getuserSymptoms();
    }

    async Task PopulateSymptomAutoComplete()
    {
        GlobalSymptoms = await symmanager.getSymptoms();


        try
        {
            autoComplete.DataSource = GlobalSymptoms;
            autoComplete.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
            autoComplete.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             DisplayAlert(ex.ToString(), ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }

        autoComplete.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {

            if (e.Value != "")
            {
                AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd = (symptom)e.Value;
            }

        };

    }

    async void HandleHelp_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblTitle.Text == "Edit Symptom")
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContextHelp(HelpConstants.EditSymptomHelpTitle, HelpConstants.EditSymptomHelpContent));
        }

        else

        {

             await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContextHelp(HelpConstants.AddSymptomHelpTitle, HelpConstants.AddSymptomHelpContent));

        }




    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Rating Slider Changed Event Handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">E.</param>
    void Handle_ValueChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

       var newStep = Math.Round(e.NewValue / StepValue);

        RatingSlider.Value = newStep * StepValue;

        SliderValue.Text = RatingSlider.Value.ToString();

    }

    public AddSymptom(CorrectiveAction action)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;


        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });

        GetUserSymptoms();


        //Set Label Titles
        lblTitle.Text = "Add Symptom";
        lblSubtutle.Text = "What symptom are you experiencing?";



        GetCorrectiveActions();
        //CommunitySwitch.IsVisible = false;


        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();

        GetSymptomHistory();

        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndex = RemedyPicker.Items.IndexOf(action.Id);
    }

    void Handle_Scrolled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        autoComplete.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }

    public AddSymptom(Symptoms symptom, bool isFeedback)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;
        symptomfeedbackmanager = SymptomFeedbackManager.DefaultManager;


           GetCorrectiveActions();

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });

        GetUserSymptoms();

        if (isFeedback == true)
        {
            this.Title = "Enter Symptom Feedback";
            lblTitle.Text = "Enter Symptom Feedback";
            lblSubtutle.Text = "Please enter your feedback";
            SymptomLabel.IsVisible = false;
            txtSymptom.IsVisible = false;
            SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Usersymptomid = symptom.Id;
            symptomToAdd.Id = symptom.Id;
            SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Description = symptom.Description;
            txtSymptom.Text = symptom.Description;

            btnAdd.Text = "Add Symptom Feedback";
            ProvidingFeedback = true;
            //CommunitySwitch.IsVisible = true;
        }

        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();
    }


    public AddSymptom(UserSymptomView symptom, bool isFeedback)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;
        symptomfeedbackmanager = SymptomFeedbackManager.DefaultManager;

        autoComplete.IsVisible = false;
        lblSearchForaSymptom.IsVisible = false;


        GetCorrectiveActions();

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });

        GetUserSymptoms();

        if (isFeedback == true)
        {
            this.Title = "Enter Symptom Feedback";
            lblTitle.Text = "Enter Symptom Feedback";
            lblSubtutle.Text = "Please enter your feedback";
            SymptomLabel.IsVisible = false;
            txtSymptom.IsVisible = false;
            SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Usersymptomid = symptom.Usersymptomid;
            SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Description = symptom.Description;
            txtSymptom.Text = symptom.Description;

            btnAdd.Text = "Add Symptom Feedback";
            ProvidingFeedback = true;
            //CommunitySwitch.IsVisible = true;
        }

        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();

        autoComplete.IsVisible = false;
        SymptomLabel.Text = symptom.Description;
        txtSymptom.IsVisible = false;

        var userSymptomToEdit = UserSymptoms.Where(Item => Item.Id == symptom.Usersymptomid);
    }


    public AddSymptom(Symptoms symptom, bool isFeedback, bool isNotification)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;
        symptomfeedbackmanager = SymptomFeedbackManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;

        GetCorrectiveActions();

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });


        GetUserSymptoms();

        if (isNotification == true)
        {
            this.Title = "Enter Symptom Feedback";
            lblTitle.Text = "Enter Symptom Feedback";
            lblSubtutle.Text = "Please enter your feedback";

            GetSymptomInfo(symptom.Id);

            SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Usersymptomid = symptom.Id;
            symptomToAdd.Id = symptom.Id;
            btnAdd.Text = "Add Symptom Feedback";
            ProvidingFeedback = true;
        }

        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();
    }

    public async Task GetSymptomInfo(string id)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Symptoms> SymptomToFeedback = await manager.getSymptomFromID(id);
        SymptomLabel.IsVisible = false;
        txtSymptom.IsVisible = false;
        SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Usersymptomid = SymptomToFeedback[0].Id;
        SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Description = SymptomToFeedback[0].Description;
        txtSymptom.Text = SymptomToFeedback[0].Description;


    }

    public AddSymptom(Symptoms symptom)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });

        GetUserSymptoms();

        //Set Label Titles
        lblTitle.Text = "Edit Symptom";
        lblSubtutle.Text = "Edit your Symptom";

        GetCorrectiveActions();

        symptomToAdd = symptom;

       txtSymptom.Text = symptom.Description;
        Symptomfeedback.Text = symptom.Symptomfeedback;



        RatingSlider.Value = symptom.Intensity;


        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();
    }

    public AddSymptom(usersymptom symptom)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        symptomfeedbackmanager = SymptomFeedbackManager.DefaultManager;

        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });

        GetUserSymptoms();

        //Set Label Titles
        lblTitle.Text = "Edit Symptom";
        lblSubtutle.Text = "Edit your Symptom";

        GetCorrectiveActions();

        SymptomToEdit = symptom;

        txtSymptom.Text = symptom.Description;
        //Symptomfeedback.Text = symptom.Symptomfeedback;



        //RatingSlider.Value = symptom.Rating;


        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();


    }

    public AddSymptom(UserSymptomView symptom)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager = SymptomsManager.DefaultManager; //intiialise the Azure Symptom class 
        weathermanager = WeatherManager.DefaultManager;
        remedymanager = RemedyManager.DefaultManager;
        imagemanager = ImagesManager.DefaultManager;
        usersymptommanager = UserSymptomManager.DefaultManager;
        //RemedyPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += RemedyPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action: async () =>
        {
            Uri ImgSource = await App.GetImage("sym");
            img.Source = ImgSource;
        });

        GetUserSymptoms();


      GetUserSymptomToEdit(symptom);    //Set Label Titles
        lblTitle.Text = "Edit Symptom";
        lblSubtutle.Text = "Edit your Symptom";

        GetCorrectiveActions();

        //SymptomToEdit = symptom;

        txtSymptom.Text = symptom.Description;
        //Symptomfeedback.Text = symptom.Symptomfeedback;



        //RatingSlider.Value = symptom.Rating;


        PopulateSymptomAutoComplete();

        autoComplete.IsVisible = false;
        SymptomLabel.Text = symptom.Description;
        txtSymptom.IsVisible = false;
        lblSearchForaSymptom.IsVisible = false;


    }



    async void GetUserSymptomToEdit(UserSymptomView symptom)
    {
        ObservableCollection<usersymptom> SelectedSymptom = await usersymptommanager.getuserSymptomInfo(symptom.Usersymptomid);
        SymptomToEdit = SelectedSymptom[0];

    }




  <summary>
Gets the corrective actions.
</summary>
<returns>The corrective actions.</returns>
    async public Task GetCorrectiveActions()
    {
        CorrectiveAction blank = new CorrectiveAction();
        blank.RemedyDesc = "";

        ObservableCollection<CorrectiveAction> CorrectiveActions = new ObservableCollection<CorrectiveAction>();
        CorrectiveActions = await remedymanager.GetUserRemedies();
        CorrectiveActions.Insert(0, blank);
        //RemedyPicker.ItemsSource = CorrectiveActions;


    }

    async void GetSymptomHistory()
    {
        var usersymptoms = await usersymptommanager.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync<IEnumerable<UserSymptomView>>("getusersyms?userid=" + Helpers.Settings.UserKey + "&isactive=0", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, null);

        foreach (var item in usersymptoms)
        {
            SymptomHistoryIDs.Add(item.Symptomid);
        }

    }


async void btnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // CheckSymptomInHistory(AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id);


        //If the autocomplete is not empty - add that symptom to the user symptom table

        if (AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd != null)
        {

            //If the user already has symptoms, loop through them to make sure that they are not adding a duplicate

            if (UserSymptoms.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (usersymptom item in UserSymptoms)
                {
                    if (item.Symptomid == AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Duplicate Symptom", "You already have recorded this symptom - please log feedback against it if needed", "OK");
                        return;
                    }

                    //Check if it is not active (i.e in SYmptom History)



                    else

                    {

                        UserSymptomToAdd.Symptomid = AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id;
                        UserSymptomToAdd.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
                        UserSymptomToAdd.Datetimeadded = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        UserSymptomToAdd.IsActive = true;




                        try
                        {
                            await usersymptommanager.AddUserSymptom(UserSymptomToAdd);
                            await AddInitialFeedback(UserSymptomToAdd.Id);
                            //await DisplayAlert("Symptom Added", "Your Symptom has been added", "OK");

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Analytics.TrackEvent("App Screen: " + Title + ": " + ex);
                            //await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            //if no symptoms are present (i.e the collection has a count of 0,just add the new usersymptom)
            else

            {
                usersymptom UserSymptomToAdd = new usersymptom();
                UserSymptomToAdd.Symptomid = AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id;
                UserSymptomToAdd.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
                UserSymptomToAdd.Datetimeadded = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                UserSymptomToAdd.IsActive = true;




                try
                {
                    await usersymptommanager.AddUserSymptom(UserSymptomToAdd);
                   await AddInitialFeedback(UserSymptomToAdd.Id);


                    //await DisplayAlert("Symptom Added", "Your Symptom has been added", "OK");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Analytics.TrackEvent("App Screen: " + Title + ": " + ex);
                    //await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
                }
            }


        }

        //If the textbox isn't empty - check if the symptom exists in the autocompelete data collection

        else if (txtSymptom.Text !=null)
        {
            foreach (symptom item in GlobalSymptoms)
            {
                if (item.Description == txtSymptom.Text)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Symptom Exists in Database", "Please search for the symptom from the autocomplete box", "OK");
                }

                else
                {

                    isNewSymptom = true;

                }
            }

            if (isNewSymptom == true)
           {
                NewSymptomToAdd.Description = txtSymptom.Text;
                NewSymptomToAdd.Symptomstatus = "pending";

                try
                {
                    await symmanager.AddSymptom(NewSymptomToAdd);


                        NewUserSymptomToAdd.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
                        NewUserSymptomToAdd.Datetimeadded = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        NewUserSymptomToAdd.Symptomid = NewSymptomToAdd.Id;
                         NewUserSymptomToAdd.IsActive = true;

                        try
                        {
                            await usersymptommanager.AddUserSymptom(NewUserSymptomToAdd);
                        await DisplayAlert("Symptom Added", "Your Symptom has been added", "OK");

                        //Our View Symptom API depends on a feedback item to be associated with the usersymptom, so we add a dummy one

                        await AddInitialFeedback(NewUserSymptomToAdd.Id);


                       }
                       catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                           await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
                       }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Analytics.TrackEvent("App Screen: " + Title + ": " + ex);
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
                }

           }
        }



  //Determines Intensity


        symptomToAdd.Rating = Convert.ToInt32(RatingSlider.Value);
        SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Rating = RatingSlider.Value.ToString();

        //Performs checks before adding to Azure table


            if (ProvidingFeedback == true)

            {
                SymptomFeedbackToAdd.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Description = txtSymptom.Text;
                SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Symptomfeedback = Symptomfeedback.Text;
                SymptomFeedbackToAdd.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;


                /*if (RemedyPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    var RemedyPicked = RemedyPicker.Items[RemedyPicker.SelectedIndex];

                }*/
            }

            else

            {

             //   symptomToAdd.Description = txtSymptom.Text;
                SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Symptomfeedback = Symptomfeedback.Text;
                symptomToAdd.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;


                /*if (RemedyPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    var RemedyPicked = RemedyPicker.Items[RemedyPicker.SelectedIndex];
                }*/
            }



            try
            {
                if (ProvidingFeedback == true)

                {
                    //if (CommunitySwitch.IsToggled == true)
                    //{
                    //    SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Posttocommunity = true;
                    //}

                    //else
                    //{
                    //    SymptomFeedbackToAdd.Posttocommunity = false;
                    //}

                    await symptomfeedbackmanager.AddSymptomfeedback(SymptomFeedbackToAdd);
                    await DisplayAlert("Symptom Feedback has been Added", "Your feedback has been added", "OK");
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new newviewsymptom());
                    Navigation.RemovePage(this);
                }

                else

                {
                    await manager.AddSymptom(symptomToAdd);
                    await DisplayAlert("Symptom Added", "Your symptom has been added", "OK");
                      await AddInitialFeedback(NewUserSymptomToAdd.Id);
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new correctiveactionconfirmation());
                    Navigation.RemovePage(this);

                }

                if (ProvidingFeedback == true)
                {
                //Set the notification reminder period
                //manager.SetSymptomReminder(TwentFourHours, Convert.ToInt32(symptomToAdd.Id), txtSymptom.Text);
                manager.SetSymptomReminder(TwentFourHours, Convert.ToInt32(symptomToAdd.Id), symptomToAdd.Description);
            }


                //Saves the notifcation object to Azure
                NotifcationToSave.Symptomid = symptomToAdd.Id;
                NotifcationToSave.Userid = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
                NotifcationToSave.MessageType = notifications.MessageTypes.SymptomReminder;
                NotifcationToSave.Notificationtime = DateTime.Now.Add(TwentFourHours).ToString();

                GetCurrentWeather(symptomToAdd.Id);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Analytics.TrackEvent("App Screen: " + Title + ": " + ex);
                //await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }


    }


    async void CheckSymptomInHistory(string id)
    {
        foreach (string item in SymptomHistoryIDs)
        {
            if (id == item)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Historical Symptom", "This symptom is in your history", "OK");
            }
        }
    }



    async Task AddInitialFeedback(string usersymptomid)
    {

        SymptomFeedback symptomFeedback = new SymptomFeedback();
        symptomFeedback.Usersymptomid = usersymptomid;
        symptomFeedback.Intensity = RatingSlider.Value.ToString();
        symptomFeedback.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
        symptomFeedback.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        symptomFeedback.Datetimelimit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToString("g");
        //  symptomFeedback.Symptomfeedback = Symptomfeedback.Text.ToString();


        try
        {

            await symptomfeedbackmanager.AddSymptomfeedback(symptomFeedback);

            //We have to null the id so that we are not always updating the existing feedback item
            symptomFeedback.Id = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Analytics.TrackEvent(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think we might need other parts of your code. Nothing here does a database call and this also doesn't look like a command and/or eventhandler for a button click. this just builds an object and sends it somewhere else. Please provide us with the relevant parts of your code

Comment: I agree with @Knoop. The most probable thing that could have happened is that maybe the event handler for a button click is calling the function multiple times, or the same event handler is called multiple times

Comment: @Knoop i have updated the question with some of the rest of my code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a wall of code so it's very hard to read. I see a lot of duplicate code and different overloads of the same function doing mostly the same thing. Anyway back to the question, from what I can see the problem in your `async void btnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)` method. You loop over the symptons the user already has to see if the `AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd` is already in the list of symptons, but every sympton that is not a duplicate adds the `AutoCompleteSymptonToAdd` by this bit of code:

```
else

{

    UserSymptomToAdd.Symptomid = AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id;
    UserSymptomToAdd.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
    UserSymptomToAdd.Datetimeadded = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    UserSymptomToAdd.IsActive = true;




    try
    {
        await usersymptommanager.AddUserSymptom(UserSymptomToAdd);
        await AddInitialFeedback(UserSymptomToAdd.Id);
        //await DisplayAlert("Symptom Added", "Your Symptom has been added", "OK");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Analytics.TrackEvent("App Screen: " + Title + ": " + ex);
        //await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
    }

}
```

I assume the funcionality you want is to only add the new sympton if there are no duplicates. So remove the `else` block and paste it's content after the `foreach (usersymptom item in UserSymptoms)` is finished. That way you're guaranteed that there is no duplicate (since it hits `return` if there's a duplicate) and you're free to add it as new sympton.

Comment: Tried that but no joy, its not duplicating when being inserted into the UserSymptom table so i dont think thats the issue, its when the data is being sent to the SymptomFeedback table is where the data is duplicating. For example i tried it again now with the updated code and it inserts into the UserSymptom table fine with no duplications but once is inserted into the SymptomFeedback table it adds the correct data but then duplicates again without adding the UserSymptomID on the duplication data.

Comment: Sorry to hear that wasn't the solution. I don't think I can help you any further then. The code is a bit of a mess so it's very hard to track what's going on. Also it doesn't help when only just now the information is added that the problem is with the SymptomFeedback table. It helps a lot of all relevant information is in the question. I hope for you someone else is able to help you, otherwise I advise you to take some time to formulate the question correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Apologies my mistake

Comment: No worries, gl with the problem